# Filter variables with typeOf

Tags: scala, reflection, scala-2.10

How do you filter variables from **typeOf**? Why checking **isMethod** is so simple and isVariable does not exist?

```
typeOf[User].members.filter(_.isMethod)
```

This is not a good idea but it works ;):

```
typeOf[User].members.filter(_.toString.startsWith("variable"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an `isVar` method, but it only exist on `TermSymbol`, not `Symbol` itself (a `TermSymbol` can also be a `val`, a method, a parameter, etc.):

```
typeOf[User].members.collect { case x: TermSymbol if x.isVar => x }
```

Or with `filter`:

```
typeOf[User].members.filter(x => x.isTerm && x.asTerm.isVar)
```

**Edit**: you are right that there is a lack of symmetry here.

Several things are represented by `TermSymbol`, and yet somehow only methods have there own `isMethod` in `Symbol`; others like `isVar` and `isVal` have not been so lucky.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know any good and simple ;) tutorial about the new reflection?

Comment: I only know of the [official reflection guide](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/overview.html). Especially the parts about all that internal reflection *vocabulary*, like Universes, Mirrors, Symbols, Types, Trees, Names, Scopes...